# History.pushState(data,title,url) concatenates (instead of replacing) url to address bar if there is a trailing slash

Tags: history.js

For example,

If I use the search bar from "www.site.com" I see "www.site.com/search", which is fine.

If I use the search bar from "www.site.com/events/" I see "www.site.com/events/search", which is silly.

Why does it do this? Is this the behavior or a history.js bug or my bug?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Give an example of what you are doing.

If your current URL in the address bar has the form: `http://somesite.com/path/`
And you pass `pushState( null, null, 'newpath' );` in this case, the link will look like `http://somesite.com/path/newpath` but if you pass a parameter as: `pushState( null, null, '/newpath' )`, in this case would look like this:
`http://somesite.com/newpath`

Comment: This is VERY dangerous if your application will ever not be deployed in the root of the server! See my answer for a workaround

Answer (score 5):

If your application is not deployed at the root (such as with a virtual directory, or just in a deeper hierarchy) then you'll end up screwing up the URL if you do `history.pushState({}, '/newpath');`

There's a couple alternatives :

1) Get your root path in a javascript variable that you can just prepend the URL to it. In this example `window.ViewModel.rootPath` is just an arbitrary place - just modify this for however you want to store global variables.

You will have to set the `rootPath` in script (example here for .NET).

```
<script>
    window.ViewModel.rootPath = "@Request.ApplicationPath";
</script>

history.pushState({}, window.ViewModel.rootPath + '/newpath');
```

2) Check if the URL ends with a `/` and if it does you need to go up 1 directory level. Note: This approach requires you to know the 'parent' directory of what you're posting - in this case `YourAccount`.

```
history.pushState({ mode: 'Club' }, '',
     (window.location.href.endsWith('/') ? '../' : '') +
      'YourAccount/ManageClub/' + id );
```

If the current URL is `/preview/store/YourAccount` then this will become `../YourAccount/ManageClub/123`.

If the current URL is `/preview/store/YourAccount/` then this will become `YourAccount/ManageClub/123`.

These with both end up at the same URL.