# History API pushState how to avoid concatenation

Tags: html5-history

I have the following two URLs (I use a single page app, so they aren't backed by any real pages):

**Solution: Urls must be start from '/' to prevent concatenation.**

1. `C/D`
2. `T`

I call `pushState()` twice passing the URLs above which results in `mysite.com/C/T`, after the second call while I'm expecting just `mysite.com/T`.

How do I prevent `pushState()` from concatenating URLs?

Comment: Checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045540/history-pushstatedata-title-url-concatenates-instead-of-replacing-url-to-add