# JS history.pushState question "skip a slash"

Tags: javascript, url, history, pushstate

So,
if the current url is 
`url.com/x/y`

 if I do `history.pushState({"z":"z"}, "" , "z")`, the url will be 
`url.com/x/z`

How to make it
`url.com/z`
??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [History.pushState(data,title,url) concatenates (instead of replacing) url to address bar if there is a trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045540/history-pushstatedata-title-url-concatenates-instead-of-replacing-url-to-add)

Comment: That link didn't answer my question but I found a way for how to do it :) 
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

It can be done by retyping the entire url path

```
history.pushState({"z":"z"}, "" , "https://url.com/z")
```